# execute shell command with mono on raspbian

Tags: c#, linux, mono, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to connect my xbox 360 controller to my raspberry pi, with c# in mono. The command to connect is 'sudo xboxdrv'. This command works if I try it directly on the raspberry pi but it gives errors when I try it from a mono console app. The code I use:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "sudo xboxdrv";

info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;

var p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();

Console.ReadLine();
```

The error I get is 'Native error= Cannot find the specified file'. I suppose it has something to do with the sudo, but without sudo the program can't work, and if possible I don't want to make my user root user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo xboxdrv` isn't a filename, it is a command with arguments. `sudo` is the filename, `xboxdrv` is the argument.

So your code should be:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "sudo";
info.Arguments = "xboxdrv";

info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;

var p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();

Console.ReadLine();
```